# Unit test projects and code coverage for all platforms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a generic question regarding code coverage in Visual Studio.

I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, and I am trying to get metrics back for a library I wrote in order to analyze the amount of code coverage my unit tests have.

The library in question is managed (C#, .NET) and built using Any CPU, but it uses P/Invoke to call into either a 64-bit or 32-bit DLL that is built in C and is native.

The C# code of this library has a lot of blocks like these:

```
if (x64)
    PInvokeX64();
else
    PInvokeX86();
```

This causes my unit tests to show about 50% code coverage because unit tests are architecture dependent. I know I can change the architecture by going to `Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture` in Visual Studio, but is there no way to test code coverage in a consolidated way for both platforms, meaning to get a unit test report back for both architectures and measure code coverage that way instead?